# How to send Data

Tags: serial, gsm

I get a GSM/GPRS Modem SIM900A

Please tell me how to open url like http://abcxyz.com/xyz.html using GPRS?

Comment: "Can i connect via ttl or rs232?" -> I believe the answer is either, *if* you attach an RS232 port to the serial lines on the pi -- which are the same pins you would use if you connected the TTL above directly instead.  I struck out part of your question here because 1) This is not all that related to the rest of the question since it is really, "How can I send any kind of data to a web server?", and 2) That is off topic here but would be appropriate on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), as it is really about generic network programming.

Comment: Check out PPP and the sim900. I have a full write up somewhere I'll try and find it

Comment: I got some commands but don't know how to use these with raspberry pi...

Comment: You don't really tell the SIM900 to download anything. You first connect to network using the SIM900 with 3G or whatever, then you use something like Python or C# with a TCP/IP stack over PPP, to get the site or send other data. Its true, the SIM900 has a TCP/IP stack but its really convoluted, it would be better to create a network interface using PPP as described, then use a programming languages TCP/IP stack to do the hard work for you.

Answer (score 1):

This guide helped me get ppp internet working:

http://www.zombiehugs.com/2011/04/ppp-with-telit-gm862-att/

For my setup, I removed the `'WAP@CINGULARGRPS.COM' *   'CINGULAR1' *` line at the bottom of `/etc/ppp/pap-secrets`.

I also added:

```
nocrtscts
nocdtrcts
```

To `/etc/ppp/peers/provider` which will disable congestion control signals (which usually aren't connected in modern uart systems).

Comment: This is the easiest way to get it going. Just need to add that you then use a programming language to use that PPP interface with the programming languages TCP/IP stack. +1  The same applies to USB 3G dongles, ie in windows, it creates a PPP interface over USB, it doesnt actually use the dongles TCP/IP stack, that is used for hardcore development, for embedded system that are not powerful enough to run things like Python or C#, only C, so they write their own TCP/IP Layer Implementation.